# Redirect incoming request to another URL in apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple question.

Right now I am receiving data to a file and then saving it to a database.

```
(
        [test] => some_data,
        [test2] => some_other_data
)
```

For example the data arrives at **example.com/receiver.php**

I am going to have to move this file to example.com/**otherfolder**/receiver.php

Note that i can't do anything with the sender, can't modify that target address.

How can I create a redirect (using htaccess, or another solution) to f**orward everything that arrives at example.com/receiver.php to example.com/otherfolder/receiver.php**?

PS: I could send the received to the other file, but it would be a double request, it would not be efficient.

So, what is the best way to redirect the incoming data?
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you insert everything into an array and send it to the next page, is there any way?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please invest time into revising it, there is an "edit" link below it, _use it_ ... What does "get this from external server" mean? Are those request arguments or what? If so, GET or POST or other? What does".com" stand for, if that meant to mimic a URL? Why don't you use a full URL so that the examples are clear? That is what "example.com" is for, actually. Why is a standard redirection rule (you will find literally _thousands_ of examples for that here on SO) not suitable for this?

Comment: @BrunoMorais is a solution, but i think its not efficient. (Doble request)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds, now after your edit, like you want a standard *internal* rewriting, *not* a redirection. Nothing spooky there. You will find literally *thousands* of examples for such a rule here on SO. Or, even better, take a short look into the documentation of the apache rewriting module, it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?receiver\.php$ /otherfolder/receiver.php [QSA,L]
```

You should implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider), then you can use a *distributed* configuration file instead (typically called ".htaccess") located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your http host.